# Should I mention potential graduate study plans during job interviews?

Tags: interviewing

I am applying for full-time employment right now for the coming year. I have also applied for graduate study this coming Fall, which I am not sure if I will choose to do or not. I will either work or go to school, but not both. My question is; should my potential grad study plans be mentioned to employers in interviews?

I can see it being a plus because it shows a desire to continue my education and learn.

I can see it being a pitfall because it makes me an uncertain candidate and potential flop.

Which is the better choice of action?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If your intention is to choose one or the other-- either you will take a full time position or you will be going to graduate school-- I wouldn't mention it in an interview.  It won't help you much-- lots of people have the desire to get advanced degrees, many fewer actually follow through and do it.  It is much more likely that employers will conclude that you're either not particularly serious about the job or that you're likely to be there only a short time before going back to school.

If, on the other hand, your intention is to go to graduate school while working, I would definitely mention that on your resume as soon as you're enrolled-- something like "candidate for `<<degree>>` in `<<program>>` at `<<university>>` 2012-present".  That is much more likely to impress an interviewer since it shows that you're taking steps to improve your skills and that you have the work ethic to handle both a full-time job and graduate school.